# split function extension

Tags: perl, split

I am learning the sample code from [split function](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/split.html).

Sample code.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

my $info = "Caine:Michael:Actor:14, Leafy Drive";
my @personal = split(/:/, $info);
# @personal = ("Caine", "Michael", "Actor", "14, Leafy Drive");
```

If change the `$info = "Caine Michael Actor /* info data */";`
How to use the `split(/ /, $info)` to export the result below.

```
# @personal = ("Caine", "Michael", "Actor", "info data");
```

Thank you.

Comment: What part exactly are you having difficulty with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Ether, Maybe i posted a dumb question. I still have some difficulty at my project. Sometime i don't know how to analyse my question, Maybe i already on the wrong way to post my queston. :-) I just tried the wrong way then i would turn back to find another way. It's my very stupid learning method.

Comment: Is there a good reason to use whitespace as a delimiter? The code samples below demonstrate that ambiguity creates complexity. A common approach is to "escape" the delimiter, for example using a backslash

Comment: @Sam and Either, Based on codadict's reply, It's a very complexity solution for my case. Next time, i should do more analysis about my question itself. Then post a exactly requiement here. :-) – Nano HE 6 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cooked something up :). Does work only for you example. Cannot generalize

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $info = "Caine Michael Actor /* info data */";
if($info=~m{/\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*/})
{
    my $temp = $1;
    $temp=~s{\s+}{##}g;
    $info=~s{/\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*/}{$temp};
}
my @personal = split(/ /, $info);
foreach(@personal)
{
    s{##}{ }g;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
C:>perl a.pl
Caine
Michael
Actor
info data
```

Comment: @codadict, Thanks a lot for your details reply. I found it's a solution for my case. It's MAGIC.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach:

Have you considered using the 3-parameter version of split:

```
$info = "Caine Michael Actor /* info data */";
@personal= split(' ',$info,4);
```

resulting in

```
@personal=('Caine','Michael','Actor','/* info data */');
```

then you would have to remove `/ *` `* /` .. to get your result...

Comment: Hi Lexu, Thank you for your reply. I never considered using the 3-parameter version of split before. You teached me more about split().

Answer (score 2):

It really is better to use regex for this:

```
$info = "Caine Michael Actor /* info data */";
$info =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+).*\/\*(.+)\*\//;
@personal = ($1, $2, $3, $4);
```

Mainly because your input string has ambiguities related to word separators not easily handled by `split`.

In case you're wondering how to read the regex:

```
/
    (\w+)   # CAPTURE a sequence of one of more word characters into $1
    \s+     # MATCH one or more white space
    (\w+)   # CAPTURE a sequence of one of more word characters into $2
    \s+     # MATCH one or more white space
    (\w+)   # CAPTURE a sequence of one of more word characters into $3
    .*      # MATCH zero or more of anything
    \/\*    # MATCH the opening of C-like comment /*
    (.+)    # CAPTURE a sequence of one or more of anything into $4
    \*\/    # MATCH the closing of C-like comment */
/x
```

Comment: Avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome by using a different delimiter and assign the match to `@personal`. Don't forget to check if `@personal` was populated. `if ( @personal =~ m!...! )`. You should also anchor the pattern.

Comment: You don't really want to match \w+ there. You don't care what the characters are as long as they aren't whitespace (that is, you don't care if they are Perl identifier characters), so you should match \S+

Comment: Better would be `if (@personal = $info =~ /.../) { ... }`. **Never use `$1` and friends unconditionally!**

Answer (score 1):

since there isn't an answer yet that handles the general case, here goes:

`split` isn't your best bet here, and since the delimiter can be both a matched and non matched character,  it will be clearest to invert the problem and describe what you do what to match, which in this case is either a string of non space characters, or the contents of a c style comment.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $info = "Caine Michael Actor /* info data */";
my @personal = grep {defined} $info =~ m! /\* \s* (.+?) \s* \*/ | (\S+) !xg;

say join ', ' => @personal;
```

that will return a list of words / contents of comments in any sequence you need.  The syntax highlighter doesn't highlight the above regex properly,  the regex is everything between `!`